# readthedocs not generating index page properly

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

Index.rst files look like this.

```
Modules
==========

Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1

   ping
   rpc
```

I have ping.rst and rpc.rst in same directory as index.rst. The html pages for ping and rpc are being created properly but index,html doesn't have proper data.

The problem seems with this

```
docs/rpc.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
docs/ping.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
```

I checked and the generated folder _build/html/_sources/ has unexpected behaviour.
The rpc.rst.txt and ping.rst.txt are same as rpc.rst and ping.rst but index.rst.txt is blank.

On using -vvvvv for sphinx command, found the below output.

```
writing output... [ 33%] index
[app] emitting event: 'doctree-resolved'(<document: >, 'index')
[app] emitting event: 'html-page-context'('index', 'page.html', {'file_suffix': '.html', 'style': 'bootstrap-sphinx.css', 'master_doc': 'inde
writing output... [ 50%] ping
[app] emitting event: 'doctree-resolved'(<document: <target...><section "ping"...>>, 'ping')
[app] emitting event: 'html-page-context'('ping', 'page.html', {'file_suffix': '.html', 'style': 'bootstrap-sphinx.css', 'master_doc': 'index
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Underlines must have the same length as the text that they underline. Try that first.

Comment: @StevePiercy - tried it, didn't work. I referred this from a similar project and it works there. There is not much difference between the two.

Comment: Let's set aside building docs on RTD. Do the docs build locally? Try `make clean; make html`. That removes any cache in your build directory, then recreates the html output. If that doesn't work, then please provide a link to a reproducible example, such as a public repository or gist.

Comment: I tried cleaning cache. 
[docs](https://github.com/Juniper/ansible-junos-stdlib/tree/master/ansible_collections/juniper/device/docs) - cloning this project and running `make html` in the directory with dependencies installed works. It will automatically generate *.rst files based on ansible2rst script.

[index](https://ansible-juniper-collection.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) --> this is the index page which doesn't have any hyperlinks to any sub-module. However, with complete path for submodule, for ex- [ping](https://ansible-juniper-collection.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ping.html) it works.

Comment: Sorry, that is a highly customized use case and too much work for me. Please provide a separate branch where you have automatically generated the `.rst`, then I can take a look.

Comment: @StevePiercy - I have generated the files and added only two modules, [docs](https://github.com/rahkumar651991/ansible-junos-stdlib/tree/readthedocs/ansible_collections/juniper/device/docs) . Can you check it now, if you can find the issue?

Comment: I successfully built the docs, and pushed a branch to [my repo](https://github.com/stevepiercy/ansible-junos-stdlib/tree/readthedocs/ansible_collections/juniper/device). I removed theme customizations and used the `nature` theme, and I commented out an import and call to `ansible2rst.main()`. What do you expect to see in the `index.html`? I see only a title and a table of contents, which is what I would expect.

Comment: I checked your repository and it generates what is expected. It seems the problem is then in ansible2rst.main file. I was looking in the wrong place. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the call to `nsible2rst.main()`. It appears this call overwrites other automation.